# is it safe to publish on github an application that will also be published in google play

Tags: android, github, google-play, keystore, electronic-signature

is it safe to publish on github an application that will also be published in google play. pre-encrypted with my keystore.

I want to publish my application in google play. But I also want to attach the repository to my resume as a sample code and is it not risky? Is there a chance that because of this, someone using decryption methods will receive  my electronic signature files (keystore etc)?

Comment: As long as you keep the keystore(and api keys, password etc) out of version control (git) and do not disclose to anyone, you should be find. That's how open source project publish their app to play store.

Comment: Nobody see the code in interviews. People see the application, UI and functioning. That's it. They will ask you questions that will prove that you made the application. Keep your source code to yourselves

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're intention is to show case the source code of you app in to any public git repos, then you should be careful about these things.

1. Never commit your code which has any third party API keys or tokens
2. Never include your app signing keys
3. Never include any sensitive information about such as any login creds, passwords, etc...
4. You should publish you're code only after uploading the relase build to the play store (In order to keep your package name available)

With all these points noted and cleared, you can publish you app code on any public git repos